# RSH connection problem while running MPI program

Tags: authentication, kerberos, rsh

I'm trying to run MPI programs on 8 machines, but I get the error

```
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 544: Connection refused
Trying krb4 rsh...
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 544: Connection refused
trying normal rsh (/usr/bin/rsh)
lagrid02: Connection refused
```

When I run it with a machinefile option, I get the error lagrid03: No route to host where lagrid03 is the neighbouring node connected to master node.

How should I rectify this ?

Answer (score 0):

> connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 544: Connection refused

Are you running RSH? (Why aren't you using MPI with SSH?)

> No route to host where lagrid03

Do you have a route to it? Can you `ping lagrid03` and get replies?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..
yes I can ping lagrid03 and get a reply.
I re-installed MPICH configured to run with ssh .
also ran 
lagrid02: env RSHCOMMAND=ssh mpirun -np 4 a.out
and I got 
  `lagrid02 connection refused
    p0_14201:  p4_error: Child process exited while making
    connection to remote process on lagrid02: 0`
FYI, lagrid02 is the Master node